# Is deleting a file "writing" or "reading"?

Tags: filesystems

A question I pondered today...

I have a meter in my Mac's top bar that shows read/write activity to the hard drive.

Is deleting a mass amount of files considered reading or writing?

Comment: write.  Read means you can read it and you can't change it, to delete requires change.

Comment: I added the [osx] tag because you mentioned that you have a Mac. If that's not right, you can [edit] your question.

Comment: @BenN I only mentioned OS X because that's where I got the idea from. I'm asking this in a general sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since deleting a file updates the file system's bookkeeping to remove the file, some data has to be written to the disk to complete the operation. (I wouldn't be surprised if some data had to be read first to figure out what place in that bookkeeping needed to be changed.)

Side note: When it comes to access control lists, deletion is definitely more like writing than reading. In the simple `rwx` access control model, write access on the directory allows deletion of files in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

It implies both although likely more writes than reads.

The file system need to read information about the files to delete, update (i.e. read/write) the directory tables to take into account the removed files, and also update (r/w) the free space bitmaps or whatever is used to track free space.